# How come this very simple javascript code crashes

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

```
var everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt = {}
var thirtyToBeAdd = 0
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt[i.toString()] = []
  everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt[i].push(i)

}
for (var z = 0; z < 2; z + 1) {

    everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt['1'].push(z)
  }
console.log(JSON.stringify(everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt))
```

It's unbelivable that this code crashes it's very simple.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> for (var z = 0; z < 2; z + 1) {
>     everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt['1'].push(z)
> }
> ```

The expression `z + 1` doesn't change the value of `z`. (Compare to `i++` which does change the value of `i`).

**Nothing** changes the value of `z`.

The end condition for the loop is never reached.

It loops forever.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is within the `for` loop.

```
for (var z = 0; z < 2; z + 1)
```

`z + 1` statement doesn't change the value of `z` variable.

You need to increase the value of the `z`.

```
for (var z = 0; z < 2; z = z + 1)
```

```js
var everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt = {}
var thirtyToBeAdd = 0
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt[i.toString()] = []
  everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt[i].push(i)

}
for (var z = 0; z < 2; z= z + 1) {

    everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt['1'].push(z)
  }
console.log(JSON.stringify(everyTimeSlotArrayObjectBuilt))
```